# Geoserver layer to leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geoserver

I have my file stored in Geoserver in wms service and
I want to display the data into leaflet.

This is the link for

The code:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html -->
<html>
<head>
<title> leaflet webviewer with Geoserver</title>
<!--Load the style stylesheet of leaflet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-Rksm5RenBEKSKFjgI3a41vrjkw4EVPlJ3+OiI65vTjIdo9brlAacEuKOiQ5OFh7cOI1bkDwLqdLw3Zg0cRJAAQ==" crossorigin=""/>
<!--Load leaflet -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-/Nsx9X4HebavoBvEBuyp3I7od5tA0UzAxs+j83KgC8PU0kgB4XiK4Lfe4y4cgBtaRJQEIFCW+oC506aPT2L1zw==" crossorigin=""></script>

  <!--Load vectorGrid plugin for Leaflet -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.vectorgrid@latest/dist/Leaflet.VectorGrid.bundled.js"></script>


<style>
/*Set the dimensions of our map */
.map {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<!--Create our map object -->
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
</body>
</html>

<script>
// Find our map id
var map = L.map('map')
// Set open openstreetmap
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);


 var wmsLayer= L.tileLayer.wms("localhost:8080/geoserver/cite/wms?service=WMS", {
        layers: 'cite:vnm_adm3',
        format: 'image/png',
        transparent: false
    });
    map.addLayer(wmsLayer);

// Set our initial location and zoomlevel
map.setView([16.4637, 107.59], 6);



</script>
```

**This is the error** :

> localhost:8080/geoserver/cite/wms?service=WMS&service=WMS&request=GetMap&layers=cite%3Avnm_adm3&styles=&format=image%2Fpng&transparent=false&version=1.1.1&width=256&height=256&srs=EPSG%3A3857&bbox=11897270....net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

How I can fix that?

Comment: Pal, you forgot `http://` at the beginning of the WMS URL.